# Is this natural deduction proof of $\exists x Fx \to G \vdash \forall x [Fx \to G]$ in predicate logic correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Like the title says, is this correct?

Edit I left out a big detail: G is a closed formula (meaning it does not contain x as a free variable).

[image]

Comment: Remember that oftentimes when proving a universal, you’re also proving a conditional. Since $\forall$-Introduction requires the use of a name that doesn’t occur in any undischarged assumptions, you’ll want to assume $F\alpha$ for a name $\alpha$ that doesn’t already occur in the proof. When you conclude the subproof, you’ll have $F\alpha \to G$, and since $\alpha$ has been discharged, you’ll get your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect. For one, notice the difference between the scopes of the quantifiers in your conclusion $\forall x [Fx] \to G$ and the one you need to derive $\forall x [Fx \to G]$. The former includes only the antecedent of the conditional while the latter includes the *entire* conditional. This difference stems from an incorrect application of *universal introduction* on line $6$. Whenever the rule is applied to a formula, it should be applied to the entire formula and not a mere component. So, instead of inferring $\forall x [Fx] \to G$ on line $6$, you should have inferred $\forall x [Fx \to G]$. Making this correction will get you closer to the conclusion you need to derive, however, I'm afraid it's still not enough. You cannot apply *existential elimination* twice over on lines $7$ and $8$. After applying it the first time to infer $\forall x [Fx \to G]$ on line $7$, the best you can do is infer the conditional $\exists x [Fx] \to \forall x [Fx \to G]$ on line $8$ via the inference rule known as *[conditional proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof)*, also known as *arrow introduction*.

Instead of assuming $\exists x [Fx]$ on line $2$, begin by assuming $Fa$ and then apply *existential introduction* to obtain $\exists x [Fx]$. Then, after applying *modus ponens* to infer $G$, you can infer $Fa \to  G$ via *conditional proof* and end your proof with *universal introduction*. I sketch out such a proof below that includes dependency numbers (appearing in curly brackets) to emphasize that the conclusion of the proof rests solely on its single premise.

$
\begin{array}{llll}
\{1\} & 1. & \exists x [Fx] \to G & \text{premise} \\
\{2\} & 2. & Fa & \text{Assumption} \\
\{2\} & 3. & \exists x [Fx] & \text{2 $\exists$ Intro} \\
\{1,2\} & 4. & G & \text{1,3 Modus Ponens} \\
\{1\} & 5. & Fa \to G & \text{2,4 $\to$ Intro} \\
\{1\} & 6. & \forall x [Fx \to G] & \text{5 $\forall$ Intro} & \square \\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I don't understand this part: "∃x[Fx]→∀x[Fx→G] on line 8 via conditional proof."

Comment: Conditional proof is another name for *arrow introduction*. You begin your proof by assuming $\exists x [Fx]$ on line $2$. Then, under this assumption, you can derive $\forall x [Fx \to G]$ after applying existential elimination on line $7$. So, by the inference rule known as conditional proof, you may derive the conditional $\exists x [Fx] \to \forall x [Fx \to G]$ on line $8$.

Comment: Okay so if I do  "-> Introduction 2-7", and if I fix the other errors in your comment (one was accidental btw I was meant to do  ∀x[Fx→G] ). But anyways would it a be correct proof? Thank you so much for the help btw.

Comment: No, applying "$\to$ Intro $2$-$7$" on line $8$ will not fix the proof (even after fixing all other errors) because it will derive the formula $\exists x [Fx] \to \forall x [Fx \to G]$, and this is not the formula you want. The formula you want to derive is $\forall x [Fx \to G]$ all by itself on a single line. See the proof I offerred in my response. I utilize a similar approach as you but I assume $Fa$ instead of $\exists x [Fx]$ on line $2$. This allows me to infer the conditional $Fa \to G$ via "$\to$ Intro" and then universally generalize to $\forall x [Fx \to G]$.

Comment: Just one more clarification, in you proof on line 2, you assumed F(a). It is not related to universal introduction or existential elimination? It is just an assumption? If yes then I understand everything, if no, I am still lost.

Comment: You are correct. The formula $Fa$ on line $2$ is just an assumption that is introduced in order to derive the conditional on line $5$ via *arrow introduction*.